# IF parent.button is pressed THEN change data for iframe graph

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

What I am looking to do, if possible, is have the data (previous or current weeks) presented within an iframe, dependent from which button is pressed in the parent of that iframe?

So for example, we have the parent with these buttons:

```
+--------+ +-------+
|Previous| |Current|
+--------+ +-------+
```

and the iframe with this graph:

```
+----------------------------------------+
|              Current Week              |
|                                        |
|                __                      |
|               |  |                     |
|      __       |  |                     |
|     |  |      |  |                     |
|     |  |      |  |                     |
|     |  |      |  |                     |
+-----|--|------|--|---------------------+
```

When the user pushes the button 'previous', I want it to change the graph data to the previous weeks data?

I have this PHP code for selecting the current week, with the first if statement being the 'How do I do it' for what I am asking in this question:

```
if current button is pressed on parent {
  //check the current day
    if(date('D')!='Mon'){
  //take the last monday
      $staticstart = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last Monday'));    
    }
    else{ $staticstart = date('Y-m-d'); }
  //always next saturday
    if(date('D')!='Sat'){
      $staticfinish = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('next Saturday'));
    }
    else{$staticfinish = date('Y-m-d');}
}
```

There will be an `elseif` statement after that which will define the previous week data, when the previous button is pushed... How do I get the iframe to know when the button is pressed?

Ideally the iframe will **know**, then **refresh** itself and load the data to whatever button was pressed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass an argument in your URL in the src attribute of the iframe...

example `pageiniframe.php?view=current`

the page will refresh and you can fetch it using php $_GET["view"]

```
$("#btn_current").click(function(){
     $("iframe").attr("src","pageiniframe.php?view=current");
});

$("#btn_previous").click(function(){
     $("iframe").attr("src","pageiniframe.php?view=previous");
});
```

Comment: i'm not awesome..i just wanted help